# How to save variable when orientation changes

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which I have to save some variable when orientation changes. How can i do this ?

like : `boolean p;`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your oncreate method

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null) 
{
p= savedInstanceState.getBoolean("flagp");
}
```

And this in activity class

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
outState.putBoolean("flagp",p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the content of the variables you want to retain in the method onSaveInstanceState.

In onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) you get passed a Bundle, which is the istructure in which you can save your variables.

Then in the Activity onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method you can check if the bundle is null and if it's not you can get you variable

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)